# Motivation to the symetric square and alterneting square

Tags: soft-question, representation-theory

I read serre's "Linear representation of finite groups", and in the 9th page he defines the symetric square and alterneting square. What is the importance of such definitions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symmetric group $S_n$ acts on the tensor power $V^{\otimes n}$ of any vector space $V$, by permuting tensor factors: $\sigma \cdot v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_n = v_{\sigma(1)} \otimes \cdots \otimes v_{\sigma(n)}$. This gives a linear representation of $S_n$ on $V^{\otimes n}$, which may be studied using the representation theory of finite groups, such as in Serre's book.

For the case of $n = 2$, $V^{\otimes 2}$ decomposes into two isotypic parts, corresponding to the two irreducible representations of $S_2$: these are the symmetric and alternating square, corresponding to the trivial and sign representation respectively. For larger $n$, it will decompose into more isotypic parts in general (although the symmetric and alternating powers are always present).